# aggregation of aggregation not allowed

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I am using google bigquery.

I want to find the average number of events for each day of the week (Sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday) for a certain time period (1 to 28 May).

For example there were 4 Sundays between May 1 to May 28, I want to find out average number of events for Sunday based on those 4 Sundays.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) AS day,
       AVG(COUNT(*)) AS average_events
FROM `table`
WHERE DATE_TRUNC(EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), DAY)
      BETWEEN DATETIME('2023-05-01 00:00:00') AND DATETIME('2023-05-28 00:00:00')
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```

this gives an error like "Aggregations of aggregations are not allowed"

edit:

I have tried the following -

```
SELECT day,
       AVG(counts) AS average_events
FROM (
   SELECT EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM event_timestamp) AS day,
          COUNT(*) AS counts
   FROM `table`
   WHERE DATE_TRUNC(event_timestamp, DAY)
         BETWEEN DATETIME('2023-05-01 00:00:00') AND DATETIME('2023-05-28 00:00:00')
   GROUP BY day
) AS t
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```

but here, the count is the same as the average.

Comment: Does it work if you put the count in a CTE and then the average in the main statement?

Comment: When I do that, the count comes the same as the average. I have explained this in the "edit" section above. thanks

Comment: Consider sharing debugging details, like sample data and expected output, that don't work with your current query.

Comment: For example there were 4 Sundays between May 1 to May 28, I want to find out average number of events for Sunday based on those 4 Sundays. What is currently happening is that all Sunday events are lumped together.

Comment: You are counting by the day of the week so you would only ever get 7 records (sun-sat) and your counts/averages will always be the same. You need to count by the actual date and then average by the day of the week

Comment: but even that approach will give the same answer right? @NickW

Comment: I mean if I divide the total events by 4 (because a total of 4 repeated days), it should give me the same answer as what you just mentioned @NickW

Comment: No - you would have counts for each day from 1st to the 28th (I.e. 29 records) and then the average for those days that are Mondays, Tuesdays, etc

Comment: so even now, I am getting average for lets say Monday by totalling all events on the 4 Mondays, then dividing by 4. By using your method, in the background the same thing would happen right @NickW

Comment: by the way, I have introduced this /4 manually in my code right now

Comment: I am dividing by 4 because for each day of the week, I have checked and there are 4 such days during my time period, for example there are 4 Thursdays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to aggregate by *day* first, and get each associated count - *then* by day of the week.

I would recommend:

```
select event_dow, avg(cnt) avg_cnt
from (
    select 
        timestamp_trunc(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp), day) event_day
        extract(dayofweek from timestamp_micros(event_timestamp)) event_dow, 
        count(*) cnt
    from mytable
    where event_timestamp >= unix_micros(timestamp '2023-05-01')
      and event_timestamp <  unix_micros(timestamp '2023-05-29')
    group by event_day, event_dow
) t
group by event_dow                                                           -- dow aggregation
order by event_dow
```

Note that I attempted to optimize the `where` clause of the query by filtering directly against original values (we can convert the bounds to unix timestamps instead) - and using half-open intervals.

Comment: SELECT list expression references column event_timestamp which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [3:52]

Comment: nope, still says "SELECT list expression references column event_timestamp which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [3:68]"

Comment: @analyst92: sorry... same player shoot again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to GBQ so you'll probably need to adjust the date functions to those used by BQ, but the following should show you how to write your own query:

```
with daily_count as (
    select trunc(event_timestamp, 'day') event_day
    , count(1) count_day
    from agg_data
    group by event_day
)
select DAYNAME(event_day), avg(count_day)
from daily_count
group by DAYNAME(event_day)
;
```